# Display Loop Results In TextArea

Tags: java, swing, loops, jtable, textarea

I've programmed a tool to check pdf files. The pdf files go through a check method: if there's an error it will display on which page it is. The pdf files are listed in a `JTable`.

When I'll right click on a pdf file in the table, a textbox appears with the error message.

I use `textArea.append(text)`. But this shows me all errors of all pdf files. I just want to see the error of the selected pdf.

```
for (int pageNo = 1; pageNo < pdf.getPages(); pageNo++) {
    try {
        PCProperty content = pdf.getContent(pageNo, ContentCollationOptions.NONE);
        if (content == null) {
            error = "Error";
        }
    } catch (PDFDocumentException exception) {
        error = "Error";
        textArea.append("failed to read content on page " + pageNo + "\n");                       
    }    
}
```

Comment: You are using external packages, please note them in the labels and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the problem is that the program is too big to provide an MCVE ...Sorry

Comment: No such thing, you can always make an MCVE, you are just not trying.

Comment: of course I tried...what do u think of me? :D

Answer (score 1):

For each new document, you can clear the existing text by passing `null` or an empty string to [`setText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText-java.lang.String-). Alternatively, `append()` a visual separator and the name of the document to retain a running history of the documents examined:

```
textArea.append("***** " + pdf.getName() + "\n");
```